# Django model method wont update model field

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have a model object with a two methods: `expired` and `pending`. The expired manager works fine and updates the field. The pending manager does not work. Here is my code.

**Side note:** I set pending to true in a view.

*models.py:*

```
class Job(models.Model):
    expired=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pending=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    purchased=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)


    def job_expired(self):
        time=self.time
        date=self.purchased
        end=date+timedelta(days=time)
        #now is defined globally
        if now > end:
            ex=self.expired=True
            #i've tried these two ways below
            self.pending=False
            #or
            ax=self.pending=False
            ax.save()
        else:
            ex=self.expired=False
        return ex
```

Let me repeat that it works fine for updating the expired field but not the pending field. I also tried a separate method:

```
       def job pending(self):
            if self.expired:
                self.pending=False
```

None of these options seem to work. Can someone please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def job_expired(self):
    time=self.time
    date=self.purchased
    end=date+timedelta(days=time)
    #now is defined globally
    if now > end:
        self.expired = True
        self.pending = False 
        self.save()

        ex = self.expired
    else:
        ex=self.expired=False
    return ex
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the changes stick you need to update the model and then save it:

1. `self.pending = False`
2. `self.save()`

Also I think you mean `field` instead of `manager`. More info on [model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/)

Comment: I actually meant method, thanks though. But if you look at the above code I've tried the self.pending=False then self.save(). That still doesnt work

Comment: @cjogbuehi okay are you sure you called .save() on the right thing? The code example doesn't look quite right: ax=self.pending=False; ax.save() - seems like it would probably raise an error and should be self.save() instead of ax.save()